# array doesn't add any data

Tags: android, json

i try to pars json array to jeson object in for loop and display it in recycler view but when i debug the array didn't run at all , why ?

```
 try {

            for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){

                JSONObject object=response.getJSONObject(i);
                Dm dm=new Dm();
                int id=object.getInt("id");
                dm.setId(id);

                String name=object.getString("name");
                dm.setName(name);

                String des=object.getString("des");
                dm.setName(des);

                String price=object.getString("price");
                dm.setName(price);

                String cat=object.getString("cat");
                dm.setName(cat);

                myArray.add(dm);

            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Comment: Is `response.length()` greater than 0?

Comment: Probably because the response.length returns an error. Can you try `Object.keys(response).length` instead and let me know ?

Comment: yes in debug mode response gets 5 and all line run but myArray.add(dm); doesnt run and jump to the first line of for and it will continue for 5 times after that exit the loop and myArray is 0 ,and because of that my recycler view nothing display

Comment: i tried object.key(response).lenght but got me an error for keys

Comment: Please add the response JSON object to your answer (without private data of course)

Answer (score 0):

you can also parse JSON in other [ways](http://www.java67.com/2016/10/3-ways-to-convert-string-to-json-object-in-java.html)

I preferred Gson for JSON parsing.